# How to make the background image fix in all different screen sizes and not move from its spot?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]

See these two circles, one is in the top left-hand corner and the other is in the bottom right-hand corner. Both circles are two different background images. I want both of them to stay at these spots and not move in all different screen sizes, including phones and tablets. I added a few media queries here and there, but it's not the best way to do it. If anyone can tell me how to achieve it, that would be great.

**[Link to the github repo](https://github.com/IssamAth/profile-card-comp)**

```
body {
    background: hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
    background-image: url(./assets/bg-pattern-top.svg), url(./assets/bg-pattern-bottom.svg);
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: -30% 1000%, 120% -1000%;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans';
}


@media(max-width: 1350px){
    body {
        background-position: -100% 1200%, 210% -1000%;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 1170px){
    body {
        background-position: -200% 1400%, 320% -1200%;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 1040px){
    body {
        background-position: -800% 1400%, 990% -1200%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        
        
    }
}
@media(max-width: 980px){
    body {
        background-position: -25000% 1400%, 26000% -1200%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
}
```

**Note I'm using Tailwind in the overall designing, but still used Vanilla CSS to design the background image.**

Comment: Hi, I think it would help us if you could make your code into a runnable snippet - and include images that we can use. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When you say 'same position' I can see the centers are to be fixed at the top left and bottom right. But what do you want the sizes of those circles to be on different viewports -  particularly on different viewport aspect ratios.

Comment: @AHaworth not really, the circles aspect ratios can stay the same. I just wanted them be fixed where they were and you gave me exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you want the radius of the circles to be something like 60vmin (ie 60% of the shortest side - in your image the sides are equal but you need to cater for keeping the circles circular when your user is in portrait or landscape modes).

This snippet positions the images so their centers are at the top left and bottom right of the body always.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  background-size: 120vmin 120vmin, 120vmin 120vmin;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: -60vmin -60vmin, calc(100vw - 60vmin) calc(100vh - 60vmin);
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, that pretty much does it!

Answer (score 0):

To keep your background image fixed, you have to use background-attachment property with the value Fixed.
Values of background-attachment property:
Scroll: It is the default value for the background-attachment property. ...
Fixed: The background image will not scroll.

Comment: I've already tried that before, but it never worked

Comment: Some versions of Safari/IOS have a problem with background-attachment: fixed.